# Why isn't this equation not a first order linear differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My calculus book says the equation:
$$y' + x^2y = y^2$$
is not linear.

Linear equations must be of the form:
$$y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$$

Is the equation not in this form with Q(x) = 0?

Comment: What about the $y^2$ term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple argument (among many others) to show that it is not a linear equation is the following. You should have $$x^2y-y^2=P(x)y-Q(x)$$ and so 
$$
(x^2-y-P(x))y=-Q(x).
$$
Since the right-hand side does not depend on $y$, we must have $x^2-y-P(x)=0$, but then $y=x^2-P(x)$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

No, because your equation must be represented in the form: $y′+P(x)y=Q(x)$
We can not fit your equation in the above-mentioned form as $y$ should appear only in the first degree but in your equation, its order is $2$.